# Do our scriptures declare that if God has to descend on earth then that place has to be somewhere in India?

Tags: scripture, gods, avatars

Do our scriptures declare that if God has to descend on earth then that place has to be somewhere in India?

Are there any shlokas in scriptures that confirm that God's avatar(human birth) will only be in the Deva Bhumi Or Punya Bhumi Bharata or India?

I asked the same question to one of my forum friends(we are not in contact nowadays) and he answered in the affirmative. But he did not tell me the exact shlokas then.

Our motive was to, in this way, dismiss the claims of any persons, who were not born in India, as avatars of Gods.

Comment: I didn't understand your last sentence.

Comment: Suppose scriptures say that God takes avatar only in Bhartvarsha or India. Then we can easily answer questions like " Is XYZ an avatar of GOd? " negatively given that that XYZ person was not born in India. @SreeCharan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do the scriptures describe some of the key features of Avataras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22701/how-do-the-scriptures-describe-some-of-the-key-features-of-avataras)

Comment: God may not have a limit by geography or astronomy or physics. India borders are given by British. And who can know now where is Jambudvipa limit - now a matter of interpretation with rough edges.

Comment: Although, I will have to check in śāstras, but it doesn't make sense for devatā's avatāra to be born in mlecchadeśa (also there has never been such a case, mentioned in śāstra afaik). Being born in mlecchadeśa, itself disqualifies one from dvijatva, etc. Bhārata alone is karmabhūmi

Comment: That might be true but deities can take birth anywhere on earth or in the universe IMO. @Bingming

Comment: @Rickross Yes, I don't think they lack the ability to take avatāras in mlecchadeśas, but the question is that have they really done, or they really prefer to, or will they?

Comment: For e.g. a devatā can take the avatāra of a terrible criminal, who slaughters innocent people (s/he has the ability), but a devatā wouldn't, for that would defeat the purpose of an avatāra.

Comment: If they have some task to achieve there they can .. but every such cases won't be stated in scriptures. @Bingming

Comment: If deities take birth then obviously the motive is to uphold Dharma so taking birth as a criminal is out of question @Bingming

Comment: @Rickross Absolutely, that's what I meant. Going to a mlecchadeśa is itself a pāpa for a dvija, and being a mleccha makes one an anadhikārin of many kriyās such as Vedādhyayana, yajñas, etc. That is why, I personally think a deva's avatāra wouldn't take janma in a mlecchadeśa. But if I do find a clear śāstrīya support for my stance, I will share it in answer. Thanks

Comment: Ok you've a point @Bingming